# why do we have to deallocate array of arrays in C++ and not just the entire "matrix"

Tags: c++, memory-management

If we have

```cpp
n=3;
m=3;
A= new int [n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
A[n] = new int[3];
}
```

we can free the memory by first calling `delete []` on all rows and then `delete [] A` at last. Why can't we just `delete [] A`?

Comment: Consider using `std::array` and/or `std::vector` in modern C++, rather than C-style arrays and manual memory management (explicit `new`/`delete`). What was good code in C++98 is often no longer good code in C++17 (and later) - things have evolved and we have better options these days.

Comment: Consider wrapping the matrix inside a class, and the implementation in that class is a flat vector.  The class converts from the dimension coordinates into the flat vector, e.g. `double& at(int x, int y) { assert(x >= 0 && x < column_size); assert(y >= 0 && y <= row_size); return v[y * column_size + x]; }`.

Answer (score 2):

How does `A` know for sure that it needs to deallocate whatever is pointed to by `A[0]`, `A[1]`, `A[2]`.

For example, what if I wrote a program like:

```
auto A = new int* [3];
int i0;
int i1;
int i2;
A[0] = &i0;
A[1] = &i1;
A[2] = &i2;
```

Then it would be a mistake for `delete [] A` to try to do anything further.

At the low level of direct memory allocations (aka direct new/delete usage) it's up to the developer to determine what all is correct.

On the other hand, C++ provides various higher level features to make things easier. Such as being able to wrap things in classes with destructors that do appropriate cleanup as well as things like `std::array`, `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr`, and so on. Ideally the developer uses these things together in a way that ensure sub-objects / sub-allocations are managed appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you `delete` an array, each element of the array will have it's destructor called. The problem is that a pointer doesn't have a destructor, you need to `delete` it explicitly.